# QGraphicsItem::boundingRect () is called repeatedly?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

`QGraphicsItem::boundingRect ()`  is a virtual function, so I re-write it to handle some of my own stuff,
then I found it is called repeatedly, but I never explicitly call it from my own code.

Who is calling it? Something like show or draw?

Comment: An important tidbit: this method is expected to be *fast*. That's why it's called repeatedly. Your implementation of it should be fast. Thus it's not very important that's it's called "repeatedly".

Answer (score 1):

From the Qt documentation about `QGraphicsItem::boundingRect` :

> Reimplement this function to let QGraphicsView determine what parts of
>   the widget, if any, need to be redrawn.

Actually is is used by `QGraphicsView` to determine whether the item requires redrawing. So it may be called multiple times by the view.